# How can I use the keyboard to move quickly between folders in Finder?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, finder

In terminal, I have set up bash aliases which give me quick access to all of the folders that I use most frequently.

Is there anything similar which I can do in Finder?

I know that I can use CMD-SHIFT-G to Go To with path completion, but this still feels slow compared to bash aliases.

Comment: If you have navigated into folder then what? After you reached destination folder you probably want work with files (maybe you even do `ls` in folder?). All gain achieved with fast access to folder is lost. There are good terminal based file managers out there ([nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn), [ranger](https://ranger.github.io), [vifm](https://vifm.info) to name a few) which give you both speed and ability to manage files. For Finder, after you opened Go To you can use TAB + arrow down for opening dropdown menu where previously used paths are nicely listed and select desired one.

Comment: I use Alfred and bash aliases for fast access to all my common folders. There are some times where I am working in Finder or must use Finder but still want to navigate between folders quickly with the keyboard. An example of this would be when a Finder filepicker pops up when I start a download in Chrome.